# Lost of mouse click capability in JDialog

Tags: java, linux, swing, centos, netbeans-7

I am developing a simple Swing application using Matisse, NetBeans GUI Builder. I am facing the same problem in all of my windows. When I open a new JDialog over my main JFrame or over other JDialog, when I click somewhere in the background window, I lose the capability to select fields with my mouse in the foreground JDialog.

[image]

In the image attached, the background window is a JFrame and I build the foreground JDialog with: new JDialog(this, true);

Could you give me a hand to solve this problem? As a hint, if after lose mouse capability I use the tab key to advance to 'ComboBox Rol' or calendar fields, and hit the space bar, I obtain again the mouse clicked and everything work perfectly as in the beginning.

Here is the code:

```
public class PrincipalUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private void jMenuItemUserManagementActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
        userManagementUI = new UserManagementUI(this, true);
        userManagementUI.setVisible(true);
    } 
}

public class UserManagementUI extends javax.swing.JDialog {
/**
     * Creates new form UserManagement
     */
    public UserManagementUI(Frame owner, boolean modal) {
        super(owner, modal);
        initOperations();
        initComponents();
        initPostOperations();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide use with a simple code example that demonstrates your problem

Comment: It's the purpose of MODAL boxes...

Comment: I have attached the code.

@Aubin I guess the purpose of modal boxes is to prevent the user to access the background window, but my problem is that I am losing the hability to select fields in the foreground JDialog with the mouse after click somewhere in the background window.
Anyway, if I change modal to false, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like incorrect parent for the dialog. Check what's the `this` when you create the `JDialog`. It could be incorrect. E.g. wrong parent dialog or frame instance.

Comment: 'this' is my JFrame instance in this particular example. It's strange because I have the same problem in all the windows of my application. I have this problem even with very simple JOptionPane like this:
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, message);
which is a simple pane to confirm the delete of some records from a JTable.

I have to say I am developing this on a CentOS Virtual Machine. I didn't have the opportunity to test it on a native OS yet, and I don't know if this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I test it on Windows and works perfectly fine, so forget it. It was a problem with CentOS or at least with the virtual machine.

Thanks for your help guys.